# Story with a Lovecraft reference published only in Russia?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a very specific book my friend guessed in a bet, chances are I'll never be able to find it myself as the hints he gave are really vague.

1. Book was published ONLY in Russian and only in Russia in 2010 with no more than 1000 copies
2. Softcover, approximately 304 pages (it is not a magazine)
3. There are ads (like in some newspapers) at the end of the book
4. Even though it has a *Lovecraft* reference, it is not a fan fiction
5. It is not a Necronomicon or the like (yeah, I tried to brute force this)

### Reference itself

In Russian:

> Я видел Юггот! Темные склепы с шестиконечными звездами, построенные не
>   людьми и не для людей, чудовищные зиккураты, покрытые слизью, слепыми
>   окнами глядящие в холодное, ...

What roughly translates as:

> I've seen Yuggoth! Dark Crypts with six-sided stars, built not by
>   humans and not for humans, monstrous ziggurats covered in slime, its'
>   blind windows are staring in a cold, ...

My Google-foo failed me as I could not find anything using this quote.

Answer (score 3):

It looks very like Lovecraft's "The Whisperer in Darkness":

> **Yuggoth...** is a strange dark orb at the very rim of our solar
> system... There are mighty cities on Yuggoth—great tiers of terraced
> towers **built of black stone...** The sun shines there no brighter than a
> star, but the beings need no light. They have other subtler senses,
> and **put no windows in their great houses and temples**... The black
> rivers of pitch that flow under those mysterious cyclopean
> bridges—**things built by some elder race** extinct and forgotten before
> the beings came to Yuggoth from the ultimate voids—**ought to be enough**
> to make any man a Dante or Poe **if he can keep sane long enough to tell
> what he has seen**...